# Uber api oauth2 error: No redirect URI with code is provided

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, uber-api

I'm following the uber ouath2 guide on [this link](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/authentication#oauth-20).

I also have a registered uber app with an app id, client id, client secret, server token and a redirect URI:

```
http://localhost:8084/testapp
```

However, when I invoke https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize?client_id=[my_client_id]&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8084/testapp, instead of receiving a link with a token code (specified as a paremeter), I'm receiving the next html content:

```html
<html class="no-js">
   <!--<![endif]-->
   <head>
      <meta content="HTML Tidy for Java (vers. 26 sep 2004), see www.w3.org" name="generator"/>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
      <title>Uber</title>
      <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport"/>
      <link type="image/x-icon" href="https://d1a3f4spazzrp4.cloudfront.net/login/images/favicon.17677bc2cadb48697a3d2da2efc65d8c.ico" rel="icon"/>
      <link href="https://d1a3f4spazzrp4.cloudfront.net/login/style-login/style.770406eec666b67f729c6f924b60ee7e.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
      <link href="https://d1a3f4spazzrp4.cloudfront.net/uber-fonts/2.0.1/superfine.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
      <link href="https://d1a3f4spazzrp4.cloudfront.net/uber-icons/3.13.0/uber-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="content text--center soft--top">
         <div class="push-gutter--sides push-small--top">
            <div id="login-content">
               <div id="fb-root"/>
               <script type="text/javascript">window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '277064115737714',
          xfbml      : false,
          version    : 'v2.2'  // good until Oct-2016
        });
        if (window.asyncUberFacebook) {
          window.asyncUberFacebook();
        }
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js';
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
               <script type="text/javascript">window.phone_email_placeholder = 'Email or Phone Number';
    window.locale = 'MX';</script>
               <p class="primary-font primary-font--semibold background-line push--top push--bottom">
                  <span>Sign In</span>
               </p>
               <form novalidate="novalidate" id="login-form" class="form" method="post">
                  <input value="1469850228-01-me6IZ7r1uyi5eZuFlK3sjFsIsAmBEkXjr_sR7f1RCAw=" name="_csrf_token" type="hidden"/>
                  <input name="access_token" data-js="access-token" type="hidden"/>
                  <a data-js="facebook-connect" class="btn btn--full btn--facebook soft-small--sides" href="#">
                     <span class="push--ends flush">Continue with Facebook</span>
                  </a>
                  <p class="primary-font primary-font--semibold background-line push--top push--bottom">
                     <span>or use email</span>
                  </p>
                  <div id="input-container" class="form-group push-tiny--top flush--bottom">
                     <input id="email" value="" placeholder="Email Address" class="text-input square--bottom" name="email" type="email"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group push--bottom">
                     <input id="password" placeholder="Password" class="text-input square--top" name="password" type="password"/>
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn--large btn--full">Sign In</button>
               </form>
               <hr id="signin-signup-separator" class="push--top push-small--bottom"/>
               <p class="text--center push-small--bottom">
                  <a class="forgot-password" href="https://login.uber.com/forgot-password">Forgot Password</a>
               </p>
               <p class="text--center">
                  Don't have an account?
                  <a href="https://get.uber.com/go/?client_id=djwOETZAgWhY57PCjTA5ZkcRAB" id="sign_up_link">Sign Up</a>
               </p>
            </div>
         </div>
         <script src="https://d1a3f4spazzrp4.cloudfront.net/login/scripts/analytics.7a14669194cf515d1963bd28ce5e8290.js" type="text/javascript"/>
         <script type="text/javascript">Analytics.init({
        services: {
            tealium: {
                account: 'uber',
                profile: 'main',
                env: 'prod',
                geo: 'MX'
            }
        }
    });</script>
         <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"/>
         <script src="https://d1a3f4spazzrp4.cloudfront.net/login/scripts/login.b8edef605ff990f6a792faf084868f5c.js" type="text/javascript"/>
         <script src="https://ws.audioeye.com/ae.js" type="text/javascript"/>
         <script type="text/javascript">Analytics.track('load', 'login.pageview');</script>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

I have searched for this kind of issue and also I have readed a lot of posts about uber api and oauth with no effective solutions.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that instead of a web page loading when you click that link in a browser, you're getting back a raw HTML response, or are you saying that you're making a GET request to that URL in some way other than opening it in a browser?

Comment: I'm doing a GET request.

I have tested it in two ways:

1. Using SOAPUI.
2. Deploying a REST using REST over Tomcat and the Apache http library.

The response is the same in both cases: the html content that I pasted in the original question.

Thanks.

Comment: * 2. Deploying a REST using Jersey over Tomcat and the Apache http library.

Comment: You're supposed to open the link in a browser, not make a raw GET request with a HTTP client. The way it works is the user navigates to the oauth url, signs in, accepts the permissions, and then is redirected to the specified redirect_url (I.E your server) with an authorization code in the URL which you can exchange for an access token.

Comment: You are right Richard Artoul. That is the correct way. 

I was sending the authorization link using a http request instead of display the oauth URL.

Thanks very much for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm responding to myself (partially), I hope this could help others.

According with Uber ouath2 guide, you must to explicitly display to your users a page where they must to interact putting their email account and password. When they do clic in "Login", they are redirected to an authorization page and, finally, when they accept the information access agreement, uber redirect to your specified uri, putting at the end, the authorization code.

However, my scenario is different and maybe I need to put another question, since what I need is to access to my own information using a registered uber app on my own uber account and, I need to automate the oauth2 validation process. I mean, this need to be an automated process where I will not there to interact with the uber agreement information statements: I need in an automated way, send my client id and all required data and retrieve an authorization code.